# SQL Query to be implemented in xCrud

Tags: php, mysql, crud

I have an SQL that I wanted to use in xCrud.

The MySQL Query is

```
SELECT r.ID, r.Name, r.Date, count(p.Route_ID) as Num_Package, SUM(status=1496) as Num_Status100
FROM drvapp_routes as r 
INNER join drvapp_packages as p 
ON p.Route_ID = r.ID 
WHERE r.Driver_ID = 1 
GROUP BY r.ID 
ORDER by r.Name ASC
```

This query shows the Route Information, including how many packages each route has, and the number of packages completed. (which has package status = 1496)

Upon reading the xCrud documentation, it doesn't show that I can use order by at all. So I'm wondering if this is even possible to use in xCrud.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a View in your MySql database and just

```
$xcrud = Xcrud::get_instance();
$xcrud->table('View_drvapp_routes_packages_completed');
```

There is also a order by function in xCrud

> order_by ( name, direction ) - sets the initial sorting of the table,
> take the field and sort order. By default - in ascending order
> ('asc').

```
$xcrud->order_by('name','desc');
```